# Create onclick method for dynamically created element using javascript and C# on MVC View

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

The problem I am facing is that when running this code the code works fine until I add this line of code between the script #option.onclick(vise());. The job i am trying to do is when the options are created when clicked or any option is selected I want to invoke the function but when this line is added whole things stops working.

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var jScriptArray=[];

@{
    for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.userClass.Count; i++)
    {
        <text>jScriptArray[@i] = "@ViewBag.userClass[@i].username";</text>
    }
}
var select = document.getElementById("global");

for (var i = 0; i < jScriptArray.length; i++)
{
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),            
        txt = document.createTextNode(jScriptArray[i]);
    option.appendChild(txt);
    option.onclick(vise()); #Error Generator
    option.setAttribute("value", jScriptArray[i]);
    select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
}

function vise() {
    console.log("hello world.");
}

</script>

<form action="DeleteUser" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Username :</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select id="global" name="username">
                                <option value="default">Select</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `select.addEventListener("change", vise)` - regardless `onclick=(vice())` is wrong syntax - you could do `onclick=vice;` but the addEventListener is the recommended method

Here is a more elegant method

```js
const select = document.getElementById("global");
select.addEventListener("change",vice)
select.innerHTML = jScriptArray
  .map(item => (`<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`)).join("")
```